# How to build my own Linux distro?

Tags: 12.04, kernel, playonlinux, distro-recommendation

Suppose, I've downloaded my kernel from http://kernel.org/ Now, How should i add desktop background with Mouse pointer, control panel, wallpapers etc.?

Please help, Surely help would be appreciated!

Comment: So, Can i use `Grub` for that as a bootloader?

Comment: You could, but you'll *still* need to write a loader for the OS that loads the kernel amongst other things like drivers.

Comment: Okay, I appreciate your answer. Only one doubt is still remaining, What Ubuntu is used for Desktop environment for e.g Desktop GUI with background, showing mouse pointer(Where we can move anywhere), My Computer properties(May be not in linux), right click showing menus etc.. for it?

Comment: What do you mean 'what Ubuntu'? Ubuntu is a Linux operating system, there are many other Linux operating systems such as Linux Mint and Fedora. If you did not know this then I really don't think you should be trying to build your own OS.

Comment: No, You got me wrong i guess. I'm saying many linux distros(Included Windows) have User interfaces. For e.g: showing mouse pointer, showing desktop with wallpapers. What packages are used in ubuntu for that? Is it unity?

Comment: you can use unity, gnome ,kde and blah blah, there are tons of desktop environments as you say desktop gui just google desktop environments for linux

Comment: @bolzao Thanks.. I was looking for this exactly! :D

Answer (score 4):

[Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) (LFS) is a project that provides you with step-by-step instructions for building your own custom Linux system, entirely from source code.

If do you want a more basic level, you can try [this tutorial](http://www.linuxuser.co.uk/news/build-your-own-distro-part-one)

Comment: Or Gentoo if you do not want to start all the way at the beginning.